# Why is loading images from Firebase Store with Glide so slowly?

Tags: android, firebase-storage, android-glide

I preload some images from Firebase Store with Glide , 40 images with sizes between  5kb-30kb and dimensions 180x256 - 480x640px..

```
                 `for(int i = 0;i<40;i++){

                              ref= storageRef
                               .child("ItemsSlike")
                               .child(array.getItem(i).getKey())
                               .child("tile.webp");


                                    glide
                                   .load(ref)
                                   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                   .centerCrop()
                                   .priority(Priority.LOW)
                                   .dontAnimate()
                                   .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                                return false;
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                                Log.i("nhy","preload:  "+resource);
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .signature(new 
            ObjectKey(((Item)array.getItem(i).getValue()).getVremeDodato()))
                                        .preload(photo,photo);
}`
```

and its take more then 10 seconds?!

```
01-22 02:30:17.949 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@aca5fbb
01-22 02:30:18.054 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@6f7ecd8
01-22 02:30:18.113 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:   
01-22 02:30:18.785 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4b62b16
01-22 02:30:18.801 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@bb53c97
01-22 02:30:18.886 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@86afe84
01-22 02:30:19.443 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@d32c66d
01-22 02:30:19.444 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@c61e2a2
01-22 02:30:19.469 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4070b33
01-22 02:30:20.321 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@8db7ef0
01-22 02:30:20.322 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@3c25c69
01-22 02:30:20.323 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41f86ee
01-22 02:30:20.866 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@69d278f
01-22 02:30:20.927 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@a919a1c
01-22 02:30:21.245 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@e0123fa
01-22 02:30:21.365 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@cceadab
01-22 02:30:21.387 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@a2c3c08
01-22 02:30:22.195 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@5502fa1
01-22 02:30:22.196 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@92d85c6
01-22 02:30:22.209 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4487987
01-22 02:30:23.439 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@48420
01-22 02:30:24.027 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@2ee31d9
01-22 02:30:24.027 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@971879e
01-22 02:30:24.076 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@edd127f
01-22 02:30:24.634 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@cfdc24c
01-22 02:30:24.696 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@c071295
01-22 02:30:24.714 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@aea7faa
01-22 02:30:25.255 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@3a579b
01-22 02:30:25.258 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@c6ab738
01-22 02:30:25.326 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
01-22 02:30:25.876 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@f48ec76
01-22 02:30:25.886 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@35cd277
01-22 02:30:25.920 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@5b00ee4
01-22 02:30:26.486 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@8d7ff4d
01-22 02:30:26.501 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@64f5a02
01-22 02:30:26.517 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@cc21f13
01-22 02:30:27.097 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@fd13550
01-22 02:30:27.110 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@6324349
01-22 02:30:27.143 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@75d144e
01-22 02:30:27.724 8472-8472/com.packtpub.materialdesign4 I/nhy: preload:  
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@125996f
```

Whether it is really the fastest possible? How to preloading images faster,for example like on Pinterest and other similar apps...I preload 40 images on start and then when scrolling,on every 20 items count preloading new 20 items,and when i scroll a little faster,new items not arrive to preloading..How to accelerate all??

Comment: Step 1: find out, what exactly is slow: server, network, your app, ...

Comment: but how do I know if my app is slow? i use firebase store,fast wifi...

Comment: If I get it right you are loading the images sequentially. Loading multiple images at the same time will be much faster (multiple threads).

Comment: Yes,sequentially...i dont know how to do that,loading on multiple threads,but learns...Thanks for your suggestion..